# freeing memory of a binary tree C

Tags: c, free, binary-tree

I would like to free memory from my allocated binary tree what traversal is the best for doing so?

```
typedef struct Node{
struct Node * right;
struct Node * left;
void * data;
}Node;


typedef int (*cmp) (void*,void *);


Node* init(void * element){
    Node * newNode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data=element;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode; 
}

void  insert(void * element, Node** root,cmp compareTo){
    if(*root==NULL){
        *root=init(element);
        return;
    }
    if(compareTo(element,(*root)->data)==1)
        insert(element,&((*root)->left),compareTo);
    else
        insert(element,&((*root)->right),compareTo);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since it's a tree, you should go with a recursive approach.

```
deallocate (node):
    //do nothing if passed a non-existent node
    if node is null
        return

    //now onto the recursion
    deallocate(left node)
    deallocate(right node)

    free node
```

Comment: If your tree is super large the recursive calls could cause a stack overflow (ahhhhhhh) in which case you'd want to go a different route (iterative), albeit you'll be increasing the time complexity.

Answer (score 14):

Think about what the different traversal types do, and keep in mind, after you free memory you're not allowed to access it anymore:

- Preorder: operation performed before visiting any children
- In-order: operation performed after visiting left subtree, before right subtree
- Postorder: operation performed after visiting all subtrees

Given the above statements, the answer should be clear.

Answer (score 7):

```
void free_tree(Node * node){
   //post-order like FatalError hinted at
       if (node != NULL) {
        free_tree(node->right);
        free(node->data); //if data was heap allocated, need to free it
        free_tree(node->left);
        free(node);
     }}
```

A cool way to check seg faults and memory leaks is to use

`valgrind --leak-check=full  ./yourProgram`

Comment: I think that it doesn't a difference, but I would expect to free the `data`, just before free-ing the `node`. I had to think twice about your code, thanks though!

Comment: this works well but I have error context "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" and "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation"

Answer (score 2):

Depth first search is best for this

Answer (score 1):

When you say "best" do you mean "correct" (i.e., won't cause chaos by accessing freed memory) or "most efficient" or what?

As far as correctness goes: Anything you like, provided you take care not to access data after freeing it. The obvious simplest approach (which I won't state explicitly because this looks kinda like homework :-) but it's what you'd do if you wanted to write as little code as possible [EDITED to add: it's what "cnicutar" posted; I hope it wasn't homework after all!]) works just fine.

You might get more efficient results (in space or time) by appropriate matching of the order of freeing with the order of allocation, but the details depend on your memory allocator and you probably shouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

```
void deallocate (struct Node * p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
        return;

    deallocate(p->right);
    deallocate(p->left);

    free(p);
}
```

> pass the root in this function and it will deallocate all heap memory used by tree

Answer (score 0):

This is how I free my memory allocation:

```
void FreeTreehelper(TreeNode* root){
    
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else {

        FreeTreehelper(root->left);
        FreeTreehelper(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled using this. You can also use `g++` instead of `clang++`. My personal choice is `clang++`:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 main.cpp -fsanitize=address
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *left{nullptr}, *right{nullptr};
};

class Tree{
    Node* root = nullptr;
public:
    ~Tree();
    void deleteTreeMemory(Node* p);
};

void Tree::deleteTreeMemory(Node* p){
    if (p != nullptr){
        deleteTreeMemory(p->left);
        deleteTreeMemory(p->right);

        /* Delete the tree nodes here */
        delete p;
    }
}

Tree::~Tree(){
    if (root != nullptr){
        deleteTreeMemory(root);
    }
}
```

Hope my answer finds a way to you all!!!