# Free all elements in a tree

Tags: c

I have tried to write a recursion to free all the elements in a tree. The data structure is a struct with info, a pointer to left child and a pointer to brother.

How can i free all nodes in the tree? I have tried post-order method, but I can't get it right
Thank you

The tree is NOT binary

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [mcve], edit your question, and post some relevant code.  People here are not mind readers.  Thanks

Comment: What *have* you tried? Please show us some code, preferably  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please tell us how it doesn't work.

Comment: I trid, but the site kept showing a message saying my post didnt meet criteria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [freeing memory of a binary tree C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181146/freeing-memory-of-a-binary-tree-c)

Comment: but i cant get an algorith that works

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think he's asking for help developing an algorithm. Given that, code wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz its it. Could you help me? I lost a lot of time thinking in an algorith

Comment: By freeing each node after the recursion from it has been completed: recurse to the child, recurse to the brother, free the node, return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, recursively or iteratively.

The recursive approach is the simplest to code. You write a "free node" function that checks if the node has any descendants or siblings and calls the "free node" on each of them, then it frees the node it was called on. Performing this "free node" operation on the root node will free the entire tree.

The iterative approach does the same thing but keeps a list of nodes to free. Here's a sketch of the iterative approach:

1. Create a list of pointers to nodes containing only the root node.
2. Take the node at the head of the list, add all its siblings and direct children to the list of nodes, then free that node and remove it from the list.
3. If the list is empty, stop, you are done.
4. Go to step 2.