# Segmentation fault after the expected output in binary tree

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
   int number;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
}
node;

void print_tree(node *root);
void free_tree(node *root);

int main(void)
{
   node *tree = NULL;

   node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
   if (n == NULL)
   {
       return 1;
   }

   // root
   n->number = 2;
   n->left = NULL;
   n->right = NULL;

   tree = n;

   n = malloc(sizeof(node));
   if (n == NULL)
   {
       free_tree(tree);
       return 1;
   }

   n->number = 1;
   n->left = NULL;
   n->right = NULL;

   tree->left = n;

   n = malloc(sizeof(node));
   if (n == NULL)
   {
       free_tree(tree);
       return 1;
   }

   n->number = 3;
   n->left = NULL;
   n->right = NULL;

   tree->right = n;

   print_tree(tree);
   free_tree(tree);
   return 0;
}

void print_tree(node* root)
{
   if (root == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   print_tree(root->left);
   printf("%i\n", root->number);
   print_tree(root->right);
}

void free_tree(node* root)
{
   if (root == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   free_tree(root->left);
   free_tree(root->right);
   free_tree(root);
}
```

My code prints out the binary tree without any problem (1, 2 and 3 with new lines) but I also suffer from a segmentation fault.I've tried to see what causes this error and debug50 indicates that the error occurs in this line:

`free_tree(root->left);`

I don't really understand why would this line cause a segmentation fault.I would appreciate the help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181146/freeing-memory-of-a-binary-tree-c

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at your `free_tree` function, which I'm guessing is for freeing up the memory allocated for the tree.

```
void free_tree(node* root)
{
   if (root == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   //some omitted code
   free_tree(root);
}
```

Do you see the issue? If `root` is not null, the recursion repeats infinitely.
This actually causes a segmentation fault as each layer of recursion allocates more memory on the stack, until there is no more memory left and a segmentation fault is thrown.

I think you were trying to write `free(root)` instead of `free_tree(root)`. This change would prevent the segmentation fault while following the original logic of your code.

Note that in most cases, you don't even need to run `free_tree` at all, as this is only being run once (before your code terminates) and most modern operating systems will free the memory for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Free tree does not free memory allocated with malloc.  free_tree() is called until it runs out of stack space.

Do this instead:

```
void free_tree(node* root) {
   printf("free_tree()\n");
   if (root == NULL) {
       return;
   }

   if (root->left != NULL) {
       free_tree(root->left);
   }
   if (root->right != NULL) {
       free_tree(root->right);
   }
   printf("do free\n");
   free(root);
   root=NULL;
}
```

To assist with debugging, add a printf("malloc\n") after each malloc.
Make sure when you run, you see the same number of malloc()'s as free()'s

Comment: You are welcome.  My initial code was incorrect.  Please take a look at this updated/edited version.